# Calculating mean of multiple matrices in R

Tags: r

What's an efficient way to calculate mean of multiple matrices of same dimension ?

If A, B are 2 x 2 matrix then,

```
A
2  3
4  5

B
6  7
8  9
```

mean(A, B) should give

```
4  5
6  7
```

Plain approach is to do (A + B + ...)/num of matrices. (and handle NA values explicitly)

Any other elegant approach or library to do this (with support of na.rm) ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Combine them into an array and use `apply`:

```
A <- matrix(c(2,4,3,5), 2)
B <- matrix(c(6,8,7,9), 2)

X <- list(A, B)
Y <- do.call(cbind, X)
Y <- array(Y, dim=c(dim(X[[1]]), length(X)))

apply(Y, c(1, 2), mean, na.rm = TRUE)
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    4    5
#[2,]    6    7
```

If `apply` is not efficient enough, you can use `colMeans` (which provides `NA` handling) with `aperm`:

```
colMeans(aperm(Y, c(3, 1, 2)), na.rm = TRUE)
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    4    5
#[2,]    6    7
```

Comment: Would the solution be different if the matrices were rasterstacks..i.e multiple rasterstacks?

Comment: Thanks for the useful answer @Roland, is there a good way to maintain `dimnames` along the way? At the moment I just overwrite using `dimnames(mean_Y) <- dimnames(X[[1]]). was a little worried about this approach although it appears to work.

Comment: @QAsena `library(abind); Y <- do.call(abind, c(X, along = 3))`

Comment: Thanks @ Roland! I don't lose the row and column names of the original matrix at the `cbind` line but they disappear at the `array()` call. And so the `apply` returns a matrix without the original `dimnames`.

Comment: Yes, I know. That's why I suggested abind instead.

Comment: @Roland, My bad, I replaced the wrong part. Thanks again!

Comment: The array manipulation could also be changed to `simplify2array(list(A,B))`

Answer (score 4):

**Update:** anyone preferring base-R will want `Reduce` instead (please upvote @thelatemail below):

```
Reduce(`+`, x) / length(x)
```

---

**Original:**

I think there's a better solution to this now, courtesy of `purrr::reduce`.

```
require(purrr)
x = list(volcano+10, volcano-15, volcano-5)
v = reduce(x, `+`) / length(x)
image(v)
```

[image]

Comment: This logic has been available in base R for many years too, with nearly identical syntax - `Reduce(\`+\`, x) / length(x)`

Answer (score 3):

Very much like Roland's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26018217/12545041), create a 3d array (though we can do it in one line with [`simplify2array()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lapply.html)).

Then rather than transposing and taking the `colMeans()`, just take the `rowMeans()`:

```r
list(A, B) |>
    simplify2array() |>
    rowMeans(dims = 2)

#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    4    5
# [2,]    6    7
```

#### Sample data

Taken from Roland's answer:

```r
A <- matrix(c(2, 4, 3, 5), 2)
B <- matrix(c(6, 8, 7, 9), 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your result to be a matrix with the same column and row names, you can create a function to pass your list of matrices to. You can also change the applied function from mean to sd or any other.

```
reduceApplyListOfArrays<- function(x){
     y<-apply(array(unlist(x), c(dim(x[[1]]), dim(x[[2]]), length(x))), 
              c(1,2), mean)
     colnames(y)<-colnames(x[[1]])
     rownames(y)<-rownames(x[[1]])
  return(y)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simple solution is

```
A <- matrix(c(2,4,3,5), 2)
B <- matrix(c(6,8,7,9), 2)
(A+B)/2
```

which gave same results as @Roland's solution