# Calculating cell means of multiple matrices w/ NA values in R

Tags: r, matrix

I'm have several matrices of the same dimensions and am trying to calculate the cell averages across the matrices while accounting for NA values.  I don't want to remove cells that have one or more NA values, but simply ignore them in the calculations.  So for example, if I have three matrices, a, b, and c...

```
a
    c1   c2
1    2    6
2    4    8

b
    c1   c2
1   NA    4
2    2    6

c
    c1   c2
1    4    8
2    6   NA
```

What I need is a resulting matrix, d, that looks like the following...

```
d
    c1   c2
1    3    6
2    4    7
```

...in which the value of cell [1,1] in d (3) would be the average of cell [1,1] in a (2), b (NA), and c (4), in this case only calculating the average of the two values that are not NA.  The value of cell [1,2] d (4) would be the average of cell [1,2] in a (4), b(2), and c(6), so on and so forth.  I can't simply use (a+b+c)/3 since I don't have 3 values for every cell.  In related posts I've seen to this the result is always an NA for the cells in d in which any of the original matrices had an NA in that given cell.

```
d
    c1    c2
1    NA    6
2    4    NA
```

It seems like this should be a relatively simple issue that I need to find an efficient solution for, as my actual datasets are 1200+ rows and 250+ columns.

Comment: I believe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26018217/3460670) should work for you, with `na.rm = TRUE`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 ar <- array(c(2,4,6,8,NA,2,4,6,4,6,8,NA),c(2,2,3))
```

In Base R you would do:

```
apply(ar, c(1,2), mean, na.rm=TRUE)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    6
[2,]    4    7
```