# Mean value of an 3D RasterLayer

Tags: r, raster

I have a stack of dimension 20x11x68 corresponding to a stack of 68 images of dimension 20x11. I want to compute the mean value of the image (so mean value on the 20x11 dimension). I tried to use the mean() function but I ended with a mean value of the 68 dates for each pixel (so a 20x11 matrix).
I also tried those method which did not worked :

```
for (i in 1:nlayers(stack_images)) {
  layer <- stack_images[[i]]
  moyennes_par_image[i] <- mean(layer[], na.rm = TRUE)
}

custom_mean <- function(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
apply(stack_images, MARGIN = c(1, 2), FUN = custom_mean)

unlist(lapply(1:nlayers(stack_images), function(i) {
  custom_mean(extract(stack_images[[i]], stack_images[[I]]))
```

Do someone know how to do this in R ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculating mean of multiple matrices in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26018216/calculating-mean-of-multiple-matrices-in-r)

Answer (score 0):

`apply(., MARGIN = c(1,2), FUN = .)` will apply the function over the first two dimensions of the array, so that is not the result you want. Instead you should apply the function `mean()` over the other dimension:

```
apply(as.array(stack_images), MARGIN = 3, FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: I had this error : Error in dimnames(x) <- list(n) : 
  dimnames' applied to something other than an array

Comment: See my update. You need to cast the raster stack to an array first.